# Impossible to display modification in shortcode code?

Tags: shortcode, cache

I'm doing a plugin using Shortcodes.
I have some classes which extend an abstract class calls Shortcode.

```
abstract class Shortcode {

    public $tag;
    public $attrs;
    public $function;

    public function __construct($tag) {
        $this->attrs = array();
        $this->tag = $tag;
        $this->function = static::className().'::getCallBack';

        add_shortcode( $this->tag, $this->function );

        $this->init();
    }

    protected function init(){
       if( !is_admin() ){
           //Front-end
           error_log('test 1');
           add_action('wp',  array( $this , 'check_page' ) );
       }
    }

    abstract public function check_page();

    abstract public static function className();

    abstract public static function getCallBack( $attrs );
}
```

**My Shortcode class**

```
class MyShortcode extends Shortcode {

    public function check_page(){
         error_log( "test 2" );
         global $post;
         $pattern = '/(\['.$this->tag.'\])/';
         if( !empty( $post->post_content ) && preg_match(  $pattern, $post->post_content ) ){
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this , 'set_styles'));
        }
    }

    public static function getCallBack( $attrs = null ){
       ...
    }

    //CSS stylesheets
    public function set_styles() {
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'wgsstyle', PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'front-end/views/css/wgs-front-end.css' );
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'wgscardsstyle', PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'front-end/views/css/wgs-cards.css' );
    }

    public static function className(){
        return __CLASS__;
    }

}
```

Something happens is weird... In debug.log, it's written "test 1" but not "test 2" and css stylesheets are still loaded.

Is there a cache for Shortcodes ? How can I reinitialize this code ?

Comment: How you call MyShortcode?

Comment: in a class named FrontEnd.php which called in the main class. I have just moved some files, that works but it seems to be fixed with the old code. But when I comment //New MyShortcode(), the page show correctly the shortcode as text. So weird !

Comment: This is probably an issue with Class inheritance and class overrides.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's this line:

`$this->function = static::className().'::getCallBack';`

I believe this is going to be the name of the abstract class. You may want to try [get_called_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) or something similar.

Try logging the `$this->function` to see what the name of the class is.

Comment: Everything is called correctly, even getCallBack()

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when you moved up some files in your plugin and you upload changes in your wordpress, that does not remove the files with the old location/path.
The solution was to remove the entire plugin and install it again.